# Pointer to a child class method

Tags: class, pointers, methods, member

So here's my code I'm working with:

```
#include <iostream>

class Node
{
public:
    void speak(){std::cout << "I'm a base node" << std::endl;}
};

class Child : public Node
{
public:
    void speak(){std::cout << "I'm a child node" << std::endl;}
};

int main()
{
    Node node;
    Child child;

    node.speak();
    child.speak();

    std::cout << "= Pointers..." << std::endl;
    Node* pnode = &node;
    Node* pchild = &child;

    pnode->speak();
    pchild->speak();
}
```

And here's the output:

```
I'm a base node
I'm a child node
= Pointers...
I'm a base node
I'm a base node
```

The `pchild->speak();` calls the `Node`'s method and not the `Child`'s one.

Now my problem is that I may have many different types of nodes, with varying number of connections. Thus I cannot declare a member pointer with a `ChildX` class, but only with a generic `Node` class. But each node will have a certain method that I want called.

I've tried to have a pointer to that method itself instead of to the class (since it would always be `int (*foo)()` type), but the compiler complains about `invalid use of non-static member function`.

So both of my approaches don't work. Neither pointer to a class, nor pointer to classes member function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Familiarize yourself with [virtual functions and polymorphism](http://learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/122-virtual-functions)  - both key concepts in c++.

In your question you simply need to define

```
virtual void speak(){std::cout << "I'm a base/child node" << std::endl;}
```

Comment: Oh, that explains some things. I've read that it's used for resolving diamond-shaped multiple inheritance, but that didn't paint the whole story. Thanks

Comment: Make sure you don't mix virtual inheritance with virtual functions. The diamond thing is even more advance than virtual functions. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance